# Why GDB examination results differ depending on whether I examined a string beforehand?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, gnu

I cannot figure out why GDB is returning different results when examining RAM addresses, depending on whether I examine my string beforehand or not:

- If I Examine my string ("hello, world" in 0x404028 address), GDB is returning a single byte when I'm examining addresses from my main function (x/x 0x401110 = 0xb8)
- If I Examine my main fuction without examining the string beforehand, GDB is returning 4 bytes instead (x/x 0x401110 = 0x000001b8)

Examining further addresses shows that 0x401111 is essentially 0x401110 shifted by 1 byte and so on.
I'm wondering which one is accurate, whether 0x401110 is actually referring to 4 bytes or a single byte. [Both results + x86_64 Assembly source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4v5O.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`help x` says:

> Defaults for format and size letters are those previously used.

Apparently the `s` format implicitly sets the size to byte size.

You can manually specify the size by adding a `b` or `w` size specifier:

`x/xw 0x401110` (32-bit)

`x/xb 0x401110` (8-bit)